# Expected value and distribution function of a simple random walk

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

Suppose we have a simple random walk on a line with starting at $0$ ,we have equal probability of moving 1 unit right or left, what's the expected value of number of steps that we reach point $r$ or $-r$ , what about random walking on a plane starting at $(0,0)$ and reaching a circle with diameter $r$.

Comment: The expected number of steps is infinite in both cases.

Comment: @AngelaRichardson: You seem to be interpreting the question to ask for the expected number of steps until the walk reaches $r$ (or equivalently $-r$). Judging from the second part, it seems more likely that the intended meaning is that the walk reaches either $r$ or $-r$.

Comment: Reaching $r$ or $-r$ should have the same expected number due to the symmetric nature of the problem,is reaching any of them have the same expected value than reaching just one of them?

Comment: the easy answer is to set this up as a martingale -- basically my comment in this post less than a month ago https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3530897/a-bound-on-the-minimum-number-of-steps-needed-for-a-2d-random-walk-to-leave-a-ci I can write this up in full if helpful but I don't know if OP understands basic martingales